# How to specify remote shell in fabric 2.4

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I need to connect via ssh to a remote host from python. I've chosen fabric 2.4 because it can run multiple commands in the single ssh-session. But I need to use a remote shell different from sh/bash/etc, my shell is powered by clixon.

All examples I've found described changing shell in fabric 1.X.

How can I configure it in fabric 2.4?

Or maybe you can advice another ssh library for python that can run multiple commands in single ssh-session?

P.S. I can't change the default shell for user in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround with paramiko(using channels):

```
class ParamikoWraper:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, port=22):
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(host, username=user, password=password, port=port)
        self.channel = self.client.invoke_shell()
        self.stdin = self.channel.makefile('wb')
        self.stdout = self.channel.makefile('r')

    def __del__(self):
        self.client.close()

    def run(self, command):
        command = command.strip('\n')
        self.stdin.write(command + '\n')
        self.stdin.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    return command, ""


remote = ParamikoWraper('192.168.33.10', "vagrant", "qwerty")
remote.run("sudo -s")  # start shell

for cmd in ["echo $(whoami) >> /root/test", "echo 2 >> /root/test", "echo 3 >> /root/test"]:
    print(remote.run(cmd))
```